# How to initialize a unichar variable in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a function that requires a unichar parameter. But could not find a nice way to initialize a unichar in swift.

I am using the following way:

```
var delimitedBy:unichar = ("," as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
```

Is there a better way to initialize a unichar in swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift can infer the type and you don't need to cast the `String` literal to `NSString`:

```
var delimitedBy = ",".characterAtIndex(0)
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode 7.1.1: `error: value of type 'String' has no member 'characterAtindex'
let dog = "a".characterAtindex(0)`

Comment: @7stud, you have a typo.  Note that the `I` is capitalized in `characterAtIndex`.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution:

```
var delimitedBy = first(",".utf16)!
```

(Note that `unichar` is a type alias for `UInt16`). This works also
with string *variables* (which of course should not be the empty string).

---

Update for **Swift 2/Xcode 7:**

```
var delimitedBy = ",".utf16.first!
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode 7.1.1:  `note: 'first' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
public func first<C : CollectionType>(x: C) -> C.Generator.Element?`

Comment: @7stud: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @7stud: If you command-click on "first" in Xcode then you'll see that it is a protocol extension method of CollectionType. Then you can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfp/CollectionType/s:vPSs14CollectionType5firstGSqqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Element_.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having trouble negotiating the docs.  I can't even find `.utf16`.  I found that one with option+click..

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 would be:

```
let delimeter = ",".utf16.first!
```