# How to set value of (initialize) unichar/UInt16 in hexadecimal in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uint16, unichar

I want to set the value of a constant [`UInt16`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UInt16_Structure/index.html) to a hexadecimal value.

I know that the way to set a Swift `Character` is

```
let myValue: Character = "\u{1820}"
```

so I tried

```
let myValue: UInt16 = "\u{1820}"
let myValue: unichar = "\u{1820}"
let myValue: UInt16 = "\u{1820}".utf16
let myValue: unichar = "\u{1820}".utf16
let myValue = "\u{1820}"
```

but none of these worked.

When searching for the answer, I mostly got SO questions about converting from `NSString` or other type.

This is surely a silly question for all you experienced Objective C programmers, but I was having a hard time finding the answer. I finally did find it, though, so I will share my question and answer to hopefully add a few keywords for others who may search for the same question in the future.

Note:

- [How to initialize a unichar variable in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846810/how-to-initialize-a-unichar-variable-in-swift) This Q&A doesn't tell how to initialize with hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had read the [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) of the Swift documentation a little more carefully you would have found it.

> Integer literals can be written as:
>
> - A *decimal* number, with no prefix
> - A *binary* number, with a 0b prefix
> - An *octal* number, with a 0o prefix
> - A *hexadecimal* number, with a 0x prefix
>
> All of these integer literals have a decimal value of 17:
>
> ```
> let decimalInteger = 17  
> let binaryInteger = 0b10001       // 17 in binary notation  
> let octalInteger = 0o21           // 17 in octal notation  
> let hexadecimalInteger = 0x11     // 17 in hexadecimal notation
> ```

So you would do

```
let myValue: UInt16 = 0x1820
```

or

```
let myValue: unichar = 0x1820 // unichar is a type alias of UInt16
```